# How can I copy files from a Python package (site-packages) to a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

The situation is this: I have a Python library that serves to communicate with some other hardware using a custom protocol. Whoever uses this solution needs a library in C code to implement the other end of the communications.

I figured that a easy way to do this is to put the files in the Python package and provide a command that copies the files to a directory of choice. The files are bundled correctly, but I can't figure how to access them. I was hoping it would be this easy:

```
# 'pkgname' is a placeholder for package in site-packages.
shutil.copy('pkgname' + os.sep + 'filename', os.getcwd())
```

But then I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pkgname\\filename'
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the copy issue? Or the problem itself?

Comment: do you really have a folder name `'pkgname\\filename'`?!

Comment: Of course not, it was just to tell what it is. Better if I write <pkgname>? I figured it was needed to specify it since site-packages is in sys.path. The files are in the package.

Comment: You need to build the folder path using `os.path`  object like `join`, and `dirname` then give it as a parameter to `copy`

Comment: And there is a way to do that knowing only the name of the installed package? I would like this to work on more than one platform (Windows, Linux).

Comment: The use also `normpath` to make is cross platform like: `normpath(join('my', 'path'))`

Comment: You really should take a look at setuptools documentation so that you could figure otu a working setup.py that would put binary and Python files in the correct folders: https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html  (it may mean, in the end, to  put the code you devised in teh setup.py file) - but it will allow one to simply run `python setup.py install` your package with no surprises, or even `pip install <package> ` if you publish it. (It allows one to use your library as part of a requirements.txt file as well, with instructions to pull from a private repository and such)

Comment: @jsbueno: The setup.py worked OK and generated the package with the files. The issue was that there are some C sources that the users of the package would need, that is use them together with their own code and build some other software. Since the users have different was of developing there is no such thing as a correct folder, so I'm providing a way to get the files from the package. Anyway, thanks for following up :)

Answer (score 6):

Found a working solution, the main thing I was looking for was the first line:

```
pkgdir = sys.modules['<mypkg>'].__path__[0]
fullpath = os.path.join(pkgdir, <myfile>)
shutil.copy(fullpath, os.getcwd())
```

Also did a silly error of not import the module in question; guess the obvious bugs are the hardest to find.